# Sliding sphere wear shape

Tags: classical-mechanics

Please refer to the figure attached. Consider a normal force is acting on the top of sphere. A constant coefficient of friction causes frictional force throughout the sliding. I want to know after this sphere slides (pure sliding no rolling) for sometime and assuming that it wears as it slides, what should be the shape of sphere after sliding? The one shown in (a) or (b)? In short, I want to know whether the worn side of sphere will be a straight line or a curved one? What will happen if a sphere slides against a sphere?  Also, I will highly appreciate if someone can refer to some good papers / books about this.

Edit: Additional assumptions

Lets assume that hardness of both surfaces is the same. Also assume that material is removed but is not attached to any of the surfaces (no adhesive wear). The phenomenon under consideration is abrasive wear (but no accumulation of wear debris). If a lubricant is in circulation, it is easy to realize this kind of wear

[image]

Comment: (a) if the surface is much harder. (b) if hardness are sort of the same. (c) no change if the sphere is harder that the surface

Comment: This is done in a test called HFRR but I don't think people generally run it long enough that the shape of the ball changes.

Comment: @Steeven can you please cite some papers about case (a) and (b)? Or some material?

Comment: It is quite well known that for contact between a soft and a hard material, the soft one will be the worn one

Comment: @Steeven In real life this is actually complicated: if there is grit or other dust, then the soft material can get the grit embedded in it and then abrade the hard material, causing the wear to be the opposite of what you might expect.  Of course in an idealised environment this does not happen, but real environments are not idealised.

Comment: I agree with you. However, I am more concerned about the "shape of wear" whether it will be a straight surface or a curved one in case of a sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the diagrams you present, I believe a straight wear(A) on the sphere is most likely.  If the hardness of the surface is less than that of the sphere, there should be no, or almost no, wear on the sphere.

(b) Would primarily occur if your surface was curved, such as if it were U shaped or in the case of sphere on sphere wearing. As you move along the curved surface, the moving sphere will be worn away along its "sides" which come into contact with the curved surface.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I edited the question to add more assumptions. Lets hear you now?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.  Assuming the lower surface is much harder than the sphere then :

If the sphere does not rotate at all as it slides then the answer is (a).
If the sphere rotates, ie rocks to and fro, as well as sliding, then it is (b).

On the other hand, if the sphere is harder than the lower surface, or the two surfaces have comparable hardness, then I think it will be something in between, even if the sphere does not rotate.

As tfb says, the *real* situation is complicated.  For example, abraded material will accumulate at the edges of the depression hollowed out of the lower surface.  What effect will that have?  Will it provide lubrication?  Or enhance the amount of abrasion at the edges?  Also, if abraded material from the harder surface gets embedded in the softer surface, this suggests to me that wear will gradually tend towards being equal on each surface.

This is a situation in which doing an experiment is essential if the outcome is crucial - by which I mean, if you will be making a decision which it could be costly to get wrong, either in time delay or money or even reputation.  Don't rely on theory or speculation.  Test it.

Comment: Just to add to this: If it's truly a "sliding" sphere, then the answer is flat, since sliding implies not rolling. A mathematically perfect sphere would touch the perfectly flat surface with only a single point, any loss of material has to come from the points that are in contact with surface for a conventional material. So it really comes down to what part of the sphere touches the surface. This isn't so much a physics question as an engineering one, as it depends a lot on the real implementation of the system.

Comment: Your answer is quite clear. But you are yourself a little skeptical. I plan to do an experiment too to verify. However, if an analytical solution is given that is always more useful and quicker than experiments. So I will wait a little before marking your answer as "accepted". I hope, someone can come with the theory or at least technical jargon of such a problem.

Comment: The trouble with theory is that you cannot be sure you are using the right one, and taking into account the most important factors. You may think it is factor X, but for this set-up or combination of materials it may be factor Y. See @tfb 's comment.  Theory can give you a good (or at least reasonable) starting point, but you need experiment for a reliable answer.